# Incorrect shape of training data while Grid Search on RNN Model

Tags: python, keras, grid-search

Please help me with the following code, which runs fine when I try to fit my model directly over the data, but fails on Grid Search (I have commented out the direct `model.fit()` part at the end of my `grid.fit()` statement, which gives me satisfactory results. Please also tell me if I am wrong in reshaping my training data as I am very new to this field. My preprocessed dataset `mt` is of shape **(96,variable)** (a list of lists)

```
x_train=[]
y_train=[]

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
padded = pad_sequences(mt)
for i in range(len(padded)):
    x_train.append(padded[i,:-1])
    y_train.append(padded[i,1:])

x_train=np.reshape(np.array(x_train),(len(x_train),len(x_train[0]),1))
#converted to 3d tensor of (batch_size,time_steps,feature_dim)

for i in range(len(y_train)):
    #print(len(lab))
    y_train[i]=to_categorical(y_train[i], num_classes=1503)
y_train=np.array(y_train, dtype='int32')

###################MY MODEL####################
def get_model():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(GRU(1, implementation=1, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01), return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1503, activation='softmax')))

    print(model.summary())

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Nadam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return model

np.random.seed(7)
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
mmodel=KerasClassifier(build_fn=get_model)
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
batch_size=[1, 4, 6, 8, 12]
epochs=[10,20,30]
#optimizer=['SGD','RMSprop','Adagrad','Adadelta','Adam','Adamax','Nadam'] #, optimizer=optimizer
param_grid=dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
grid=GridSearchCV(estimator=mmodel,param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=1, cv=3)
grid_result=grid.fit(x_train,y_train)
#model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_split=False, batch_size=1, shuffle=True,
 #         callbacks=False)
```

Comment: what do you mean failed, complete error message please.

Comment: ```ValueError: Invalid shape for y: (64, 482, 1503)``` This was the error message. I understood that 482 stands for the length of each of the padded sequences, and 1503 was the number of classes for the one-hot encoded label data, y_train

Comment: I am not sure what the value of the first axis (64) represents though

Comment: Okay so probably 64 stands for 2/3rd of 96 (total size of my train data, mt=96x482 after padding) since I am using 3-fold cross-validation. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to reshape your training data `x_train`. You have to change your `input_shape` of the `GRU` layer.

```
model.add(GRU(1, implementation=1, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01), return_sequences=True, input_shape=(len(x_train[0]),)))
```

However, if you want to keep your reshaped training data then your input shape would be `input_shape=(len(x_train[0]),1))`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I actually didn't pad my list of sequences before, since they had variable lengths, so I used the ```None``` in shape. I have corrected it to (len(x_train[0],1) now